# Pretouching JVM heap is slow

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, jvm-hotspot

My simple hello world program takes over 10 minutes to start when `-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch` is enabled with a large heap:

```
$ time java -Xmx1000G -Xms1000G -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch Test
Hello World!

real    10m9.330s
user    1m9.932s
sys 9m8.128s
```

This is unexpected because pretouch was [parallelized in Java 9](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2685771), and I am using Java 11. I still see that pretouch is only using one thread.

Why is heap pretouching running serially instead of in parallel? Do I need to configure additional options to enable parallel pretouching? I am using an 80 core server with 2 TB of memory.

Java version:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Debian-3bpo91)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Debian-3bpo91, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Java code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of the time is spent in kernel space. You should profile it, e.g. with perf, to figure what's happening there. It could be paging, THP defragmentation, KSM or other things.

Comment: The linked articles says: *"Pretouch was parallelized for the **G1 collector** in JDK9"* --- So, are you using the G1 collector? You didn't ask for it.

Comment: @Andreas G1 is the default in 11. https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/248

Comment: @the8472 That was Java 9. Things change. How do OP know *for sure* that G1 is the active collector? OP **didn't ask for it**. If you rely on a feature that requires a certain condition, you better **make sure** that condition is met.

Comment: How did you see that it was using one thread? BTW, `AlwaysPreTouch` is highly inefficient and does not guarantee that all heap pages stay in RAM. I'd suggest using `mlockall` instead.

Comment: I think you will find the JVM are still poor at distributing applications and GCing across numa regions

Comment: @apangin interesting, what does `AlwaysPreTouch` guarantee then?

Comment: @Eugene That all the heap pages are accessed before JVM starts, i.e. the pages are allocated in physical RAM or in swap. I'm not sure I fully understand the question.

Comment: @apangin no no, you answered my question. Thank you!